# configure trunk interface in linux centos7

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, vlan, interface, trunk

I have connected 2 trunk interface to server(centos 7 server) nic port for setup vlan tagging.

And have enabled 8021q module in server.

Configure two physical interfaces as bonding as below

Physical Interface 1: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno5

```
DEVICE=eno5
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
```

Physical Interface 2: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno6

```
DEVICE=eno6
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
```

bond0 config file: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
NAME=bond0
TYPE=Bond
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=802.1q miimon=100 lacp_rate=1 xmit_hash_policy=layer2 updelay=200 downdelay=200"
```

Then i created vlan tag interface for vlan communication

vlan 91 config: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0.91

```
DEVICE=bond0.91
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
VLAN=yes
VLAN_ID=91
ONPARENT=yes
PHYSDEV=bond0
IPADDR=192.168.91.1
PREFIX=24
NETWORK=192.168.91.0
GATEWAY=192.168.91.100
```

vlan 89 config: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0.89

```
DEVICE=bond0.89
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
VLAN=yes
VLAN_ID=89
ONPARENT=yes
PHYSDEV=bond0
IPADDR=192.168.89.11
PREFIX=24
NETWORK=192.168.89.0
GATEWAY=192.168.89.100
```

but at a time i can ping only one vlan either of two vlans.

Also enabled static route in centos serves side.(route and rule files for interfaces)

Any idea to configuration work properly?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
# echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
# sysctl -p
```

Comment: This needs a lot more explanation to be useful.